# Install a binary from a third party package in yocto

Tags: jpeg, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to have jpegtran command in my custom linux image built by yocto. I have added IMAGE_INSTALL += jpeg in my image.bb file for that. I checked build directory as well to check whether jpegtran is being generated by jpeg package build or not, and it is there. But jpegtran is not being installed in image. What am I missing here? Do I need to write .bbappend for this usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look `${WORKDIR}/packages-split` for `libjpeg-turbo` or `libjpeg` (depending on which version of OpenEmbedded you're using). There you should find `jpegtrans` in the package `jpgeg-tools`. See also [recipe](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-graphics/jpeg/libjpeg-turbo_1.5.1.bb) for details on how the packaging is being done for `libjpeg(-turbo).

All applications that `libjep(-turbo)` installs, gets package into `libjeg-tools` by the following lines:

```
DESCRIPTION_jpeg-tools = "The jpeg-tools package includes client programs to access libjpeg functionality.  These tools allow for the compression, decompression, transformation and display of JPEG files and benchmarking of the libjpeg library."
FILES_jpeg-tools = "${bindir}/*"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I read that recipe but I do not find a line where it is installing jpegtran command on the image. Can you please point me if I am missing something?

Comment: Well, I assume that it's `Makefile` installs are the helper applications. See my updated answer.

Comment: Installed jpeg-tools package instead of jpeg and now I see jpegtran in my image. IMAGE_INSTALL += jpeg replaced with IMAGE_INSTALL += jpeg-tools